# How to remember user's point on audio timeline as it's done on Youtube?

Tags: javascript, ajax, audio, html5-audio

I'm using html5  with a custom made audio player. So I'd like to let users remember the point on audio player timeline to let it be played from the last moment on next time they visit the website. As an example you can see it on videos on Youtube, where you can continue watching video from the point you dropped last time. How to do it?

Any code examples I will be very happy to see. Thanks

Comment: All HTMLMediaElements (of which the HTML5 Audio element is one) have a `currentTime` property. This can be read to get the current time, and written to seek. There's also things like localStorage that can let you store information between sessions. Try to combine those into a solution, then if it still doesn't work, post the code you tried and we'll help you from there.